# Elegant way to add "selected" into a dropdrown form using PHP

Tags: php, apache

I have a form that looks like this:

```
$guests = 2; // Just for testing
$form = 'Guests<br /><select name="guests">
             <option value="0">0</option>
             <option value="1">1</option>
             <option value="2">2</option>
             <option value="3">3</option>
             <option value="4">4</option>
             <option value="5">5</option>
             <option value="6">6</option>
             <option value="7">7</option>
             <option value="8">8</option>
             <option value="9">9</option>
             </select>';
```

But the list of guests can be up to 100, so I probably shouldn't do a check for which value is selected manually.

What would be a good way for me to make the selected value become the selected value when the user sees this form?

Thanks!

Comment: any reason you can't use a text input and then both limit to be digit-only and against boundaries (up to 100)?

Comment: @leon a dropdown will be less confusing to the users in this case.

Comment: @leon that is a good idea though

Comment: I think it's not interesting to go through all of the 100 options to get to 100, but I'm not the one to either use or design your system. You have much better understanding of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$guests = 2; // Just for testing
$form = 'Guests<br /><select name="guests">';

for($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++)
    $form .= "<option value='$i'{$guest == $i ? ' selected=\'selected\'' : ''}>$i</option>";

$form .= '</select>';
```

**EDIT:** `$i < 101` was pretty lame...

Answer (score 3):

What I normally do with dynamic select menus is use a foreach loop over an array, and just check each item.

Something like:

```
$dropdownName = "guests"; //Name of dropdown
$defaultValue = "0"; //value to select if there isn't one already set
$items = array('name'=>'value', 'anotherName'=>'anothervalue'); //items, name=>value

echo '<select name="'.$dropdownName.'">'; //Start Select

$selectedItem = (isset($_POST[$dropdownName])?$_POST[$dropdownName]:$defaultValue); //If a value is set, use it, otherwise use the default

foreach ($items as $name=>$value) //build select
{
    echo '<option value="'.$value.'"'.(($selectedItem == $value)?' selected="selected"':'').'>'.$name.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: If you replace `selected` with `selected="selected"`, you also get XHTML correctness for free. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can store the value this value in a hidden field and on document.ready(), you can assign the selected value of drop down top the value of hidden value.

A solution that works but may not be efficient for some users...